# Neural net decision boundaries are perpendicular to true boundaries

Tags: python, neural-network

I have built a small neural net taking in two inputs. Two neurons in hidden layer, one neuron in output layer. The results are "mirror images" ie the decisions boundaries are perpendicular to the true boundaries. Does anyone know how this might be happening on what mistake I may have made?

[linear data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzanf.png)

[nonlinear data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA8Zs.png)

```
import random, numpy, math


lr = 0.1 #learning rate
dt = '4' #data type 1: linear 2: curve 3: box 4: XORish
epochs = 100000
tda = 50 #training data amount


def step(x): #step function
  if x > 0:
    x = 1
  else:
    x = 0
  return x

def error(truth, output):
  return 0.5 * (truth - output)**2

def sig(x): #sigmoid activation
  return 1/(1+numpy.exp(-x))


#weights
w = [random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]



#biases
b = [random.random(),random.random(),random.random()]


def Net(x, y, t) : # t is truth (or target)


  h1 = x*w[0]+y*w[1]+b[0] #summation in h1, first neuron in hidden layer
  h1out = sig(h1) #sigmoid activation


  h2 = x*w[2]+y*w[3]+b[1]
  h2out = sig(h2) 


  z = h1out*w[4]+h2out*w[5]+b[2] #z is output neuron
  zout = sig(z)

  e = error(t, zout) # e is error



  #backpropagation, partial differentiations to find error at each weight and bias
  e5 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * h1out #e5 is error at weight 5 etc
  e6 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * h2out

  e1 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) * x
  e2 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) * y
  e3 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) * x
  e4 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) * y


  be3 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout))
  be1 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[4] * (h1out * (1 - h1out)) 
  be2 = (zout-t) * (zout * (1 - zout)) * w[5] * (h2out * (1 - h2out)) 



  #updating weights and biases
  w[0] = w[0] - (e1 * lr)
  w[1] = w[1] - (e2 * lr)
  w[2] = w[2] - (e3 * lr)
  w[3] = w[3] - (e4 * lr)

  w[4] = w[4] - (e5 * lr)
  w[5] = w[5] - (e6 * lr)


  b[2] = b[2] - (be3 * lr)

  b[0] = b[0] - (be1 * lr)
  b[1] = b[1] - (be2 * lr)



train_data = []

while len(train_data)<tda: #makes training data
  x = random.randrange(100)
  y = random.randrange(100)
  if dt == '1':
    if x+y>100:
      truth = 1
    else:
      truth = 0
  elif dt == '2':
    if x*y>1000:
      truth = 1
    else:
      truth = 0
  elif dt == '3':
    if x>50 or y>50:
      truth = 1
    else:
      truth = 0
  elif dt == '4':
    if x+y>60 and x+y<140:
      truth = 1
    else:
      truth = 0
  if [x,y,truth] not in train_data:
    train_data.append([x,y,truth])



for n in range(epochs): #EPOCHS
  for i in train_data:
    Net(i[0], i[1], i[2])
  if n%1000 == 0 and n != 0:
    print (n, 'epochs')

  if n%5000 == 0:

#every 5000 epochs the net is fed new test data and results are plotted 

    test_data = []

    while len(test_data)<(50): #makes test data
      x = random.randrange(100)
      y = random.randrange(100)
      if [x, y] not in test_data and [x, y, 0] not in train_data and [x, y, 1] not in train_data:
        test_data.append([x, y])


#classifying the test data with the net
    for i in test_data:
      x = i[0]
      y = i[1]


      h1 = x*w[0]+y*w[1]+b[0]
      h1out = sig(h1)


      h2 = x*w[2]+y*w[3]+b[1]
      h2out = sig(h2)


      z = h1out*w[4]+h2out*w[5]+b[2]
      zout = step(z)


      i.append(zout)


    print (test_data)
    print (w, b)

#plotting results
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x0 = []
    y0 = []
    x1 = []
    y1 = []
    xt0 = []
    yt0 = []
    xt1 = []
    yt1 = []

    for i in train_data:
      if i[2] == 0:
        x0.append(i[0])
        y0.append(i[1])
      else:
        x1.append(i[0])
        y1.append(i[1])

    for i in test_data:
      if i[2] == 0:
        xt0.append(i[0])
        yt0.append(i[1])
      else:
        xt1.append(i[0])
        yt1.append(i[1])

    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(xt0, yt0, 30, color = 'red')
    plt.scatter(xt1, yt1, 30, color = 'blue')
    plt.scatter(x0, y0, 10, color = 'orange')
    plt.scatter(x1, y1, 10, color = 'green')
    plt.title(str(tda)+" training data, "+str(epochs)+" epochs \n Red/Orange are small things, Blue/Green are big things \n Orange/Green are training data, Red/Blue are test data")
    plt.xlabel("Width")
    plt.ylabel("Height")
    plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: Interesting. Mind sharing the code? It's almost impossible to say what went wrong without knowing what exactly you were running.

Comment: sure. here is a link to the code
https://repl.it/join/jsvyluca-duncduncan

Comment: pastebin may be?

Comment: the code is now in the question

Comment: Damn... If you wrote the whole thing, kudos. But debugging this reading and trying to understand and remember each variable is going to be a nightmare. Since you are indeed getting the correct boundary but perpendicular, the back prop itself is working. I am on a mobile and can't run it right now. But can you start with simple debugging techniques like comparing the loss value for a random sample with the same calculated on paper to see if you missed something there, and then try comparing gradients and layer outputs similarly. Sorry man, but anyone except you debugging this will take longer

Comment: haha thanks. Yeah the backprop is fine. It works now. The problem was the input values. They are all between 0 and 100. Now ive scaled them down to all be between 0 and 1 and it works. I still get 'mirror images' sometimes tho, on some more complicated data types. mysterious

Comment: Even if you take 0-100 uniform random variables in input vector, the effect would be saturation of sigmoid, not enough gradients to train on, something of that sort. I still wonder what was causing the perpendicular boundaries.  Did you try debugging as I said, by comparing the gradients? May be you can try for a small say 3 dimension input, just to see if gradient dimension is what you expect